# Operators suddenly not working

Tags: time, vbscript, operators

A week ago I wrote this script which starts up when you log in and then greets you according to the time of the day. This morning it suddenly suddenly said: "Invalid time" (it would do that if all other `elseif` options wouldn't match the time). This used to work until today.

Here's my code:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
ctime = Time()
usr = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%")
if ctime > "06:00:00" and ctime < "12:00:00" then
    objShell.Popup "Good Morning, " & usr, 5, "", 4096
elseif ctime > "12:00:00" and ctime < "18:00:00" then
    objShell.Popup "Good Afternoon, " & usr, 5, "", 4096
elseif ctime > "18:00:00" and ctime < "23:59:59" then
    objShell.Popup "Good evening, " & usr, 5, "", 4096
elseif ctime > "00:00:00" and ctime < "06:00:00" then
    objShell.Popup "Good night, " & usr, 5, "", 4096
else
    objShell.Popup "Invalid time", 5, "", 4096
end if
```

EDIT: It seems like it works again, now that it's 10 o' clock but for some reason it didn't work before 10, I guess there is still an error in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing values of *time* and *string* data subtype. The [Comparison Operators (VBScript) reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hck4s70(v=vs.84).aspx) is quite bit unclear about it (or about automatic data subtype conversion); I guess conversion *time* to *string* with an alternative leading zero manipulation, for instance `#09:10:12#` time converts to either `"9:10:12"` or `" 9:10:12"` string. So force *time* comparison using time literals by enclosing them in number signs (`#`), for instance `#06:00:00#` instead of `"06:00:00"`.

However, there are still gaps in your logic: for instance `#06:00:00#` or  `#12:00:00#` or `#18:00:00#` time does not match any `if` nor `elseif` condition and will give *Invalid time* output.

Hence, instead of

```
if ctime > "06:00:00" and ctime < "12:00:00" then
```

use either

```
if ctime >= #06:00:00# and ctime < #12:00:00# then
```

or

```
if ctime > #06:00:00# and ctime <= #12:00:00# then
```

and improve all `elseif` analogously.